# Error de doble mensaje

Tags: javascript, html, web

Cuando introduzco en año por ejemplo 2011 solo me debería salir el mensaje de error pero me sale ese y la sentencia de la condición de edad<15. Como puedo arreglar eso por favor.

```
<script>
var nombre="": var apellido=""; var año=0; var edad=0; var edad2=0;
function boton()
{
 nombre = prompt("¿Cuál es su nombre?","");
 apellido = prompt("¿Cuál es su apellido?","");
 año= prompt("Ingrese un año entre 2000 y 2010", 0);
if((año>=2000) && (año<=2010))
edad=2021-parseInt(año)
else
alert("Los datos son incorrectos, ingrese nuevamente");
azar=Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt(edad2))
edad2=parseInt(azar)+parseInt(edad)
 if(edad<15)
alert(nombre+" "+apellido+" tiene "+edad+" como la edad fué menor a 15, generámos un valor aleatorio donde obtuvimos al azar el "+azar+", ahora lo sumamos con la edad anterior y así tenga una mayor edad: "+azar+" MAS "+ edad+   "="+edad2);
else
edad2=parseInt(edad)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Duda, ¿Por que tanta falta de uso de llaves y cierres? literalmente resolvi 2 problemas del código agregando sus respectivas llaves. JS puede fallar el semicolon facilmente si lo ignoras de ese modo que lo haces.

Answer (score 0):

Entra en el if(edad<15) porque en un principio le das valor 0 a edad y edad2 entonces siempre va a ser menor que 15 aunque no entre en el primer if. Te recomendario estructurar tu código y poner los if else de la siguiente forma:

```
if((año>=2000) && (año<=2010))
   edad=2021-parseInt(año)
else
   alert("Los datos son incorrectos, ingrese nuevamente");
   azar=Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt(edad2))
   edad2=parseInt(azar)+parseInt(edad)
if(edad<15 && edad != 0)
   alert(nombre+" "+apellido+" tiene "+edad+" como la edad fué menor a 15, generámos un valor aleatorio donde obtuvimos al azar el "+azar+", ahora lo sumamos con la edad anterior y así tenga una mayor edad: "+azar+" MAS "+ edad+   "="+edad2);
else
   if (edad >= 15 && edad != 0)
       edad2=parseInt(edad)
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo corregí